# HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH

Tags: amazon-athena, aws-glue

I'm getting this error from AWS Athena:

```
HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH: There is a mismatch between the table and partition schemas. The types are incompatible and cannot be coerced. The column 'id' in table 'db.app_events' is declared as type 'string', but partition 'xxxxx' declared column 'data.entity_price' as type 'double'.
```

there is no connection with those fields but it gives an error. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: what is the query you are trying to execute?

Answer (score 7):

Schema is kept at partition level unless you inherit schema from table. See this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/updates-and-partitions.html

also discussed here as well: 
[How to solve this HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890280/how-to-solve-this-hive-partition-schema-mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE columnName newColumnName type CASCADE;

Comment: Doesn't work in spark-sql 3.4